# What does % do in the following code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm reading The "Rails 3 Way" and on page 39, it shows a code sample of the match `:to =>` redirect method. In that method the following code exists. Whilst I know what modulo does with numbers, I'm unsure what the % is doing below because both path and params are clearly not numbers. If anyone can help me understand the use of % in this situation, I'd appreciate it.

```
proc { |params| path % params }
```

Answer (score 10):

That's probably the [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-25) method which works a lot like `sprintf` does in other languages:

```
'%05d' % 10
# => "00010"
```

It can take either a single argument or an array:

```
'%.3f %s' % [ 10.341412, 'samples' ]
# => "10.341 samples"
```

**Update**: As Philip points out, this method also takes a hash:

```
'%{count} %{label}' % { count: 20, label: 'samples' }
# => "20 samples"
```

Of course, this is presuming that `path` is a String. In Ruby you never really know for sure unless you carefully read the code. It's unlikely, but it could be `%` meaning modulo.

The thing you can be sure of is it's calling method `%` on `path`.

Comment: downvoted because you didn't address what happens when `params` is a hash, which it usually is

Comment: @Phlip I've added a note about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It does string interpolation. In the simplest case, it's equivalent to:

```
"foo %s baz" % 'bar'
#=> "foo bar baz"
```

However, you can use more complex format specifiers to interpolate from Array or Hash objects too, such as the Rails *params* hash. See the [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-25) and [Kernel#sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) methods for details on how to construct a valid format specification.

Comment: Specifically, the `"foo = %{foo}" % { :foo => 'bar' }` notation uses `%{foo}` to expand a hash by value. Note that certain other languages would have used `%(foo)s` there...

Comment: @Phlip That's a great example of how to do interpolation using hash keys in the format specifier. Thanks for adding a constructive comment!